# chef_gem compile time execution

Tags: chef-infra, recipe

I am using below code such that chef_gem will work after downloading gem file. But chef_gem is invoked first after converge even if i am specifying compile_time to true.

```
remote_file "/home/scripts/#{File.basename(node['EBSMount']['open4_url'])}" do
  source node['EBSMount']['open4_url']
end    

chef_gem 'open4' do
      action :install
      source "/home/scripts/#{File.basename(node['EBSMount']['open4_url'])}"
      clear_sources true
      compile_time true
    end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gem\_package and chef\_gem installation from a local file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35968017/gem-package-and-chef-gem-installation-from-a-local-file)

Comment: My Problem here is about execution time of chef_gem where as in another question is about installation from local file system. Even though i am specifying compile_time to true, chef_gem resource getting invoked first after convergence.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]
try modify the `compile_time` as follows -

```
chef_gem 'open4' do
  #...
  compile_time true if Chef::Resource::ChefGem.instance_methods(false).include?(:compile_time)
end
```

You can chain the execution steps using the keyword '**notifies**'. The best practice is to set the dependent resource block action as "nothing" and use notifies keyword to invoke the action.

```
remote_file "/home/scripts/#{File.basename(node['EBSMount']['open4_url'])}" do
  source node['EBSMount']['open4_url']
  notifies :install, 'chef_gem[open4]', :immediately
end    

chef_gem 'open4' do
  action :nothing
  source "/home/scripts/#{File.basename(node['EBSMount']['open4_url'])}"
  clear_sources true
  compile_time true
end
```

Here is Chef documentation on "[Notifies Resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#notifies)"

Comment: Yes, i tried this option but i am curious about compile_time option. How does that work.

Comment: @SASI modified the answer